# JQuery datepicker: What is the use of Date:new Date ("07/19/2014")

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery datepicker I am not getting why to use new Date to show event in datepicker. I can show events when i pass dates manually but how to pass dates when dates are coming from database.

For instance think that I have `var events =<?=events?>;` which contains `title`, `id`, `event_date`. In which `event_date` is in `2014-07-21` format which is not showing.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zrz9t/1151/) is the example which i tried.

I have same table with same fields. but i am fetching events from database.

Here is the plunker link please see if you can edit and show events without using "new Date". in events array i just want {date:"2014-07-21"} in this format the event should be shown. or please tell me what i have to do to edit my database returned array to show in datepicker .Link [plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/Zrz9t/1151/)

here is my simple html code i have included my database events object into it please see running and editing below code. i tried your code did'nt worked for me. if you uncomment working events array of object it works fine.but not working for my JSON data retuned from database. i Have to show this in JSON data.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>cal </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    table.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td.highlight > a {
        background: url("images/ui-bg_inset-hard_55_ffeb80_1x100.png") repeat-x scroll 50% bottom #FFEB80;
        color: blue;
        background: red;
        border: 1px solid #FFDE2E;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="cal13">Hover me</button>
    <div class="cal1" style="display:none"><div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //my original data in json format
var events =[ 
             {"Title":"my date booked", "event_date":"2014-07-11"},
             {"Title":"my date booked", "event_date":"2014-07-12"},
            ];

/* the working data
    var events = [ 
    { Title: "Five K for charity", Date: new Date("02/13/2011") }, 
    { Title: "Dinner", Date: new Date("02/25/2011") }, 
    { Title: "Meeting with manager", Date: new Date("03/01/2011") }
];     */       

$(".cal13").mouseenter(function(){
console.log("in now");
$(".cal1").show();
$(".cal1").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var result = [true, '', null];
        var matching = $.grep(events, function(event) {
            return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
        });

        if (matching.length) {
            result = [true, 'highlight', null];
        }
        return result;
    },
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        var date,
            selectedDate = new Date(dateText),
            i = 0,
            event = null;

        while (i < events.length && !event) {
            date = events[i].Date;

            if (selectedDate.valueOf() === date.valueOf()) {
                event = events[i];
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (event) {
            alert(event.Title);
        }
    }
});
}).mouseleave(function(){
$(".cal1").hide();
    console.log("out now");
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rory McCrossan for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you use `php`, if so then you can combine [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to reverse the order of you `event_date` to `21-06-2014`, like this:

```
$event_date = "2014-07-21";
$pieces = explode("-", $event_date);
$pieces = array_reverse($pieces);
$result = implode("-", $pieces);
echo $result; //you will get 21-07-2014
```

By doing so, I think you can assign it to your `datepicker`..

**TESTED**

```
var events =[ 
    {"Title":"my date booked", "event_date":"2014-07-11"},
    {"Title":"my date booked", "event_date":"2014-07-12"},
];
var dt_events = [];
events.forEach(function(item){
    dt_events.push({"Title": item.Title,  Date: new Date(item.event_date)});
});

dt_events.forEach(function(item){
    alert(item.Title + ' ' + item.Date);
});
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V6CWC/1/), currently I don't have enough time to try it with Datepicker. However I think that would do.. Hope it helps..

Comment: sir @user3003216 i am not facing problem for date format events can be shown with my database stored format, you just have a look at link i provided, in which every date is created with Date new("2014-07-21"). i am using codeigniter. I am using that datepicker which i mentioned above link. so when i assign var events = <?=events?>; How can i assign dates because u see in link these dates are initiated with New Date. Here is the plunker see if you can remove that "new Date" from events array and use only date i,e "2014-07-13" to show i n calender [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Zrz9t/1151/)

Comment: To see events in link please visit 2011 year I forgot to create new link so gave existed one.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i am sorry for the late, but i tried your code. I have edited and written my code with my JSON data. you can edit the simple html file now. please see if you can do this, i will mark this for best answer if you do.

Comment: No sir :-( still not showing in datepicker.. Now time is in more complicated form Fri Jul 11 2014 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST). sir i am beginner in Jquery. whenever you have time you can see running entire html please sir. untill and unless you see you will not understand the problem. i am waiting for your answer. Please see running entire code.

Comment: Actually i tried what you did see my code, i have also created on var obj={}; and pushed the dates in it using foreach then pushed this obj in var events=[]; which is array of objects. I think something going wrong in my code. cant able to figure out. please try when you get time. I am marking you best answer i learn some things from you so marking you best. i will mark correct if dates appear on my datepicker i hope you can do it. :-)

Comment: Hello sir I got the solution I have just disabled these dates from datepicker. see my code var array = ["2014-07-14","2014-07-15","2014-07-16"]

$('.cal1').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
});

Comment: Good to hear that.. I still don't have enough time to debug your code.. Sorry.. Busy time at work.. ^^

Comment: Its ok sir... anyhow i am marking your answer as correct because anyhow answer is there in comments also i learnt some things too! dont you think mine question is also usefull?? ;-).cheers. happy coding..